# checking Internet connection with Reachability is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

hi I’m trying check internet connection in my application. so for that i have already imported the reachability h file and m file in project. I’m getting some issues with that now. its working only if internet connection available its not working in without the net connection..

here this is the code which have used..

```
-(BOOL)reachable {
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"https://www.google.co.in/"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {

    UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Internet" message:@"You dont have internet connection to send message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alertOne show];
    [alertOne release];


}

    return YES;
}
```

i have already used this same code in other projects its working their but here its showing the alert message when internet connected its not showing when its not connected ...

this viewdidload code...

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self reachable];
```

pls can any tell me how to resolve this...

thanks

Comment: Your hostname is nonsense and `reach` in this code is almost certainly `nil`. Get rid of the `https`, it's not a URL, it's a host name.

Comment: hi @JasonCoco already tired without https its not working thats y i have tried with http that also its not working..

Comment: It's because `reach` is `nil`. Either because the host name can't be resolved, or because you gave it nonsense like a URL. The problem is that if you message `reach` when it is `nil`, you are *always* going to get a `0` returned. Unfortunately, `NotReachable` is defined as `0` as well, so you must check that `reach` is actually set before you try and use it.

Comment: ok @JasonCoco im new to ios development pls tell where to change the code and what i have to put

Comment: You need to give it a proper host name or check that it actually returns a value. I'd suggest just going with @vidhyanand answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
//(or)
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus != NotReachable)
    {
        //Reachable ..Network connection is available
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"Network Error No Network Available ");


        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please connect to an Internet connection to Register" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];

        [alertView show];

    }
```

It works for you...

Comment: hi @Vidhyanand i have tried ur code also its not working...

Comment: I checked with above code by replacing the line with
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];
Also ..It works fine...for me..

Comment: @Vidyanand i tried with that also its not working for me pls if u dont can i have ur gmail id or skype id so i can explain the issue clearly plss

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cause of the problem, but it is and always was wrong to call `reachable` in `viewDidLoad`. The reason is that `viewDidLoad` is *way* too early to call code that might put up an alert view. In `viewDidLoad`, your view is not even in the interface yet.

Another very odd thing is that your `reachable` method both detects reachability and puts up the alert. It returns a BOOL but you are throwing it away. You should be saying

```
if (![self reachable]) { // ...
```

and putting up the alert view there, not inside the `reachable` method.

Still another very weird thing is that your `reachable` method *always* returns YES. That's nuts. You should return YES if the URL is reachable and NO if it is not. Otherwise, what is the point of returning a BOOL at all?

Comment: Also, at this point, the fact that you are not using ARC is a bad sign.

Comment: hi @matt im using ARC also its not working

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this steps,

1>make property of   Reachability and NetworkStatus;
 in your appDelegate.h

```
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    Reachability* reachability;
   NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus;

}
@end
```

2>Create Notification method when reachability changed in applicationDidBecomeActive

```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];
    reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];
    remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {
        if(DEBUG_MODE){NSLog(@"no");}

    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {if(DEBUG_MODE)
    {NSLog(@"wifi");}

    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {if(DEBUG_MODE){NSLog(@"cell");}

    }

}
```

3> declare reachabilityChanged

```
    -(void)reachabilityChanged:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags
{

 if([self isReachableWithFlags:flags])
    {
        if(self.reachableBlock)
        {
            self.reachableBlock(self);
        }
    }
else
{
    if(self.unreachableBlock)
    {
        self.unreachableBlock(self);
    }
}

// this makes sure the change notification happens on the MAIN THREAD
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                        object:self];
});

}
```

Thanks.